# Toggle multiple divs on and off (almost working)

Tags: javascript, css, hide, toggle, show

I have this:

```
function toggleCharts() {
var x, divArray = ["item_4746983", "item_4491867"];
for (x in divArray) {
    if (x) {
        document.getElementById(divArray[x]).style.display = 'block';
    }
}

<button onClick="toggleCharts();">Charts</button>
```

and this:

```
#item_4746983 {
    display:none;
}

#item_4491867 {
    display:none;
}
```

`item_4746983` & `item_4491867` are thumbnails that I want to show or hide when you click on charts

The code works and they display when I click the button but I can't figure out the code to hide them by clicking on it again.

Comment: this is not the problem, but you should **not** use `for..in` to iterate on those kind of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Instead of styling by id, style by class:

```
.hiddenThumbnail {
    display:none;
}
```

Then apply and remove the `hiddenThumbnail` class to and from the two items. This makes your css code smaller, and makes everything generally more maintainable. [See this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/781965) for a guide on how to modify the classes.

Alternatively, use a library like [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/node-view.html) to do it (I'm sure jquery has similar functions also).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the div is shown already and change the display.  The following code should work.

```
var div = document.getElementById(divArray[x])
var shown = div.style.display;

if ("block" == shown) {
    div.style.display = none;
} else {
    div.style.display = block;
}
```

Here is a link that shows various ways of doing what you want:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

Answer (score 0):

***[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BDUXS/)***.

```
function toggleCharts() { 
    var divArray = ["item_4746983", "item_4491867"], i, ele;
    for (i=0; i < divArray.length; i++) {
        ele = document.getElementById(divArray[i]);
        ele.style.display = ele.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```